# What would be the regex for extracting this specific numerical value from this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Assuming that I have the following string (see below), what would be the regex code (javascript) to extract the the numerical value that is surrounded by spaces from it (in this case, 200)?

```
#18 of 200 lodges in France
```

I am using `\d+` to extract the value 18 but I am stuck on how to deal with the value 200.

Comment: Ask yourself what's special about 200? How do _you_ know not to choose 18 instead? Is it because it is not at the start? Is it because it has spaces around it? Is it because it is three digits? Is it because it starts with 2?

Comment: If you know that it is 200, then use 200. You need to phrase the question more abstract. What other values can be there? Give examples you want to match. Very important, give examples which should NOT match. Give many examples. Better still, describe in an abstract way what you want to match. Maybe digits not following "#"? Maybe the second set of digits? Maybe the third set of non-blanks? Mayb the second to last "word" shorter than 4?

Comment: @Yunnosch Value can be anything from 1 upwards but it is always surrounded by spaces.

Comment: Do you know the game "tabu"? You have to describe what you want to achieve, but you are not allowed to say "200", "18", "#" or "digit".

Comment: So, did you try to search for digits which are surrounded by blanks? You probably do not want them in the result, but it gets you closer to the goal ` \d+ `.

Comment: Which regex flavor are you using? (Which language/tool?) Are lookarounds supported?

Comment: @Yunnosch I have updated my question. Also, I need to input that regex code in an application which will perform the extraction. It says "javscript regular expressions".

Comment: Good work improving your question.

Comment: However, can I ask a favor of you? You have a decent amount of reputation and the accompanying privileges here. Can I convince you to help with improving the general quality of questions? For that I would ask you to encourage people answering your questions to do more than drop useable code. I know that is asking something of someone who needs a solution. But maybe a comment, "That seems to work, but could you explain how exactly you achieved that?". Note that I already honored your good work on this question, so there is no pressure. It is just something I would appreciate.

Comment: @Yunnosch well noted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

```
import re
re.findall(r'\b(?<!^[#])\d+', '#18 of 200 lodges in France')
```

Output

```
['200']
```

Comment: I need the 200 only as output.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: OP asks for javascript solution.

Comment: @user3115933: Be aware that negative lookbehind is not supported in all browsers, for example Firefox